# NoClassDefFoundError after running Proguard on JavaFX application

Tags: java, ant, javafx-8, proguard

I am receiving the following error after running proguard on an JavaFX application.  The application runs fine if proguard is not used.  I have searched StackOverflow and found some posts but I have had zero success with trying some of the various answers.

`Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "main" java.
lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/win32/StdCallLibrary$StdCallCallback
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplicationWithA
rgs$153(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$44/1645995473.run(Unk
nown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(Unknown
 Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/355629945.run(Unkn
own Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/1337124724.run(Unk
nown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(Unknown S
ource)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/1915503092.run(Unk
nown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/1963387170.run(Unknown
 Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary$St
dCallCallback
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 28 more
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unk
nown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Sou
rce)
        ... 5 more`

I have the following in my pro configurations trying to keep just about everything in the error message to hopefully stumble upon a solution.

```
-keep class com.sun.javafx.** { *; }
-keep interface com.sun.jna.** { *; }

-keep class com.sun.jna.** { *; }
-keep class com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary { public *; }
-keepclassmembers class * extends com.sun.jna.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}
-keep interface * extends com.sun.jna.** { *; }
-keep class * implements com.sun.jna.** { *; }
```

And with verbose turned on, I see the following when running the ant build script.

```
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.WeakReferenceQueue'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.beans.event.AbstractNotifyListener'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.css.Selector'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.css.StyleCache'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.css.StyleCache$Key'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager$1'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager$CacheContainer'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.css.StyleMap'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.css.Stylesheet'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.fxml.LoadListener'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.fxml.ParseTraceElement'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.geom.BaseBounds'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.geom.Ellipse2D'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.geom.Path2D'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.geom.PathConsumer2D'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.geom.PickRay'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.geom.Point2D'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.geom.RectangularShape'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.geom.Shape'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.geom.Vec2d'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.geom.Vec3d'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.geom.transform.Affine3D'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.geom.transform.AffineBase'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.geom.transform.BaseTransform'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.geom.transform.CanTransformVec3d'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.jmx.MXNodeAlgorithm'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.jmx.MXNodeAlgorithmContext'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.perf.PerformanceTracker'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.runtime.async.AsyncOperation'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.runtime.async.AsyncOperationListener'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.scene.CssFlags'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.scene.DirtyBits'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.scene.LayoutFlags'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.FXVK'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.scene.input.PickResultChooser'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.scene.text.GlyphList'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.scene.text.HitInfo'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.scene.text.TextLayout'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.scene.text.TextSpan'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.scene.traversal.Direction'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.scene.traversal.ParentTraversalEngine'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.scene.traversal.TraversalEngine'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.scene.web.Debugger'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGShape$Mode'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.stage.WindowEventDispatcher'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.stage.WindowPeerListener'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.tk.ImageLoader'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.tk.PlatformImage'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.tk.TKDragGestureListener'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.tk.TKPulseListener'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.tk.TKScene'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.tk.TKStage'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.javafx.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.javafx.tk.TKStageListener'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.AltCallingConvention'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.Callback'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.Callback$UncaughtExceptionHandler'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.FunctionMapper'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.Library'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.Native$ffi_callback'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.NativeMapped'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.TypeMapper'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.Version'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.BaseTSD'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Guid'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinError'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT$OVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.win32.StdCall'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary$StdCallCallback'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.AltCallingConvention'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.Callback'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.Callback$UncaughtExceptionHandler'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.CallbackThreadInitializer'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.FromNativeContext'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.FunctionMapper'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.IntegerType'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.Library'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.Memory'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.Native'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.Native$ffi_callback'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.NativeLong'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.NativeMapped'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.Pointer'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.PointerType'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.Structure'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.Structure$StructField'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.TypeMapper'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.Version'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.WString'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.BaseTSD'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.BaseTSD$LONG_PTR'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.BaseTSD$ULONG_PTRByReference'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Guid'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Guid$GUID'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Guid$IID'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Ole32Util'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Tlhelp32$PROCESSENTRY32'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase$FILETIME'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase$MEMORYSTATUSEX'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase$OVERLAPPED'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase$PROCESS_INFORMATION'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase$SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase$STARTUPINFO'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase$SYSTEMTIME'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase$SYSTEM_INFO'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef$DWORD'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef$DWORDByReference'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef$HINSTANCE'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef$HMODULE'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef$HWND'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef$LCID'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef$LPARAM'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef$LRESULT'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef$UINT_PTR'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef$WPARAM'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinError'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT$FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT$HANDLE'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT$HANDLEByReference'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT$HRESULT'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT$LARGE_INTEGER'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT$OSVERSIONINFO'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT$OSVERSIONINFOEX'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT$OVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.ptr.ByReference'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.ptr.LongByReference'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.ptr.PointerByReference'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.win32.StdCall'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.**' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary$StdCallCallback'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary' to keep library class 'com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary'
```

**Work Around**
I am able to work around the issue and get it to run if I add the following to the proguard configuration.

```
-dontoptimize
```

I think I really want to optimize though, it doesn't seem like it does much obfuscating with that in place.  How can I get around the issue but with doing the most obfuscating I can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if anyone stumbles upon this and has a similar problem I have fixed mine by not moving my jar file to another location before running it.  I was getting a NoClassDefFoundError error because the classes that were trying to be used were located in a libs folder that were not accessible after I moved the .jar (and not the libs folder).  A very easy issue to fix but with so many varied suggestions found on StackOverflow I failed to think of what now seems incredibly obvious.